# Loading Image into Picturebox from URL

Tags: c#, http, webbrowser-control, picturebox, bots

I'm programming an algorithm in C# to download an image from a website and my software automatically fills all the required fields and presses the download button. The problem is that I'm not able to load the image. The dialog box to download image on Internet Explorer is appearing, so I need to get the url of the picture after clicking the button "generate" and load it into the picture box. My code:

```
private void simpleButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string i = "0";
    HtmlElement hu = webBrowser3.Document.GetElementById("data-text");
    hu.Focus();
    hu.SetAttribute("Value", txtEncodeData.Text);

    HtmlElement hu1 = webBrowser3.Document.GetElementById("color");
    hu1.Focus();
    Color c = customColorBlender1.SelectedColor;
    string hex = c.R.ToString("X2") + c.G.ToString("X2") + c.B.ToString("X2");
    hu1.SetAttribute("Value", hex);

    HtmlElement hu2 = webBrowser3.Document.GetElementById("effect");
    hu2.Focus();
    if (comboBoxEdit1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        i = "1";
    }
    hu2.SetAttribute("Value", i);
    webBrowser3.Document.GetElementById("generate").InvokeMember("click");

    t.Interval = 1000;
    t.Start();
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);

}

void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t.Stop();

    String url = Convert.ToString(webBrowser3.Document.GetElementById("download").InvokeMember("click"));
    MessageBox.Show(url);
    pictureBox15.ImageLocation = Convert.ToString((Uri)webBrowser3.Document.GetElementById("download").InvokeMember("click"));
}
```